# Laravel 4: View [a.b] not found.

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu and tried to run a Laravel app which used to run there.

After configuring everything, mysql is working nicely, but it throws up this View Not Found error in the following function.

```
public function getOtherBoards($bname)
{
    // Get Board Data
    $boardData = Board::getNthBoard_byBoardName($bname);

    // Get Posts Data
    $postsData = Post::getAllPosts($boardData[0]->bid);
    $numberOfPosts = json_decode($postsData, true);
    $numberOfPosts = count($numberOfPosts);

    return View::make('boards.myBoard'.Input::get('bname'))->with(array('boardData' => $boardData, 'postsData' => $postsData, 'numberOfPosts' => $numberOfPosts));
}
```

Error is: View [boards.myBoard] not found.
Although it worked on Windows.

**Further info:**
- My app is on Desktop and I run it using `php artisan serve`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Input::get('bname') stand for ?

Comment: Have you tried switching `Input::get('bname')` call with the variable (`$bname`) passed to the method?

Comment: What's the URL you're using and what's the correct name of the view?

Comment: @AnandPatel you can replace it with $bname, it's the board name that needs to be loaded.

Comment: @VytautasLozickas Yes I just did, to no avail. This is the URL that loads the board.
[After](http://localhost:801/boards/other-boards/Zain%27s%202nd%20Board)
[Now](http://localhost:801/boards)

Comment: any what about your board names ? directory struct is like boards/myBoard/board1 ?

Comment: @lukasgeiter the URL is in above comment, and the board name is myBoard.blade.php under boards directory.
So views/boards/myBoard.blade.php

Comment: @AnandPatel I think i'm down a blind alley. Directory struct is view/boards/myBoard.blade.php
But why did I concatenate ".$bname" and it worked on Windows :/

Comment: Okay now if, I just write ('boards.myBoard'), it still isn't working. It still says View not found.

Comment: Have you tried testing other routes? Does other views work?

Comment: are you sure fine name is myBoard.blade.php (B is capital) ?

Comment: My goodness me. I'm really sorry guys. It was my mistake. The B is lowercase. Embarrassed. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Linux is case sensitive you need to write B in lower case

```
return View::make('boards.myboard'.Input::get('bname'))->with(array('boardData' => $boardData, 'postsData' => $postsData, 'numberOfPosts' => $numberOfPosts));
```